# Health check failing for Cosmos DB emulator

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to run Cosmos DB emulator using docker. Following is the docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  cosmosdb-emulator:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 10251:10251
      - 10252:10252
      - 10253:10253
      - 10254:10254
    mem_limit: 4g
    cpus: 2.0
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=5
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=${LOCAL_IP}
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "curl",
          "-f",
          "-k",
          "https://${LOCAL_IP}:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem",
        ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - cosmos-data:/tmp/cosmos/appdata
volumes:
  cosmos-data:
```

I can see the following on the terminal, on running docker compose for the above file.

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  Recreated                                                                                    0.1s
Attaching to cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | This is an evaluation version.  There are [172] days left in the evaluation period.
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Starting
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 1/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 2/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 3/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 4/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 5/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 6/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 7/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 8/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 9/6 partitions
cosmosdb-cosmosdb-emulator-1  | Started 10/6 partitions
```

It gets stuck on started 10/6 partitions. Why dont I see a proper startup message?

why is the Health check failing? I tried to health check with the following as well :

`curl -k --fail https://192.168.29.32:8081/_explorer/healthcheck`

I can see this on the terminal on running the above curl command : `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404`

Finally, why there are 10/6 partitions that got started, while I configured the number of partitions to be 5

P.S : I can access the portal on `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`
I am also able to create database/containers.

.env file :

```
LOCAL_IP=192.168.29.32
```

Answer (score 0):

The health check is failing because the URL you are using (https://${LOCAL_IP}:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem) is not the correct endpoint for the health check. The emulator health check endpoint is https://${LOCAL_IP}:8081/_explorer/healthcheck. Update the health check and let us know if that works for you.

Comment: That endpoint (_explorer/healthcheck) does not seem to exist. Using image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator (latest)